# Can safeTransfer cause reentrancy?

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin, reentrant-attacks

so I'm learning about reentrancy.
I understand that external calls can result in reentrancy.

Recently, I have started learning about Openzeppelin libraries, and got to know about safeERC20, which is a wrapper around ERC20 operations.

I want to know whether

**token.safeTransfer(...)**

can cause reentrancy issues?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It can still be vulnerable to reentrancy attacks.

The only thing safe about `safeTransfer` is that if a token returns false on transfer or any other operation, a contract using `safeTransfer` will revert and hence it gets auto handled.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the token. Usually, standard *ERC20* tokens do not contain callback hooks thus making it impossible to re-enter. However, there exist modifications, for instance, *ERC777* that allow arbitrary callbacks via hooks that are called during token transfers.